# OpenMP problems

Tags: c++, openmp

How to parallelize this algorithm using OpenMP? I tried different options, but the execution time only increases.

```cpp
void gammaEncoding(string& input, string& gamma, string& result)
{
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int Ti, Gi;
    char BUFF;

    for (i = 0; i < ITERATION_COUNT; i++)
    {
        if(j == gamma.length() - 1)
            j = 0;
            
        Ti = input[i] - FIRST_SYMBOL;
        Gi = gamma[j] - FIRST_SYMBOL;
            
        BUFF = FIRST_SYMBOL + (Ti + Gi) % SYMBOL_NUMBER;
        result += BUFF;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, there seems to be no heavy calculations performed so I assume ITERATION_COUNT must be huge. Each thread needs to process large chunks of consecutive data, otherwise there will be no gain. You may want to do your own threading, as openmp does not always make it easier to implement.

Comment: @SvenNilsson Could you show me how to do this? I have tried many options, but I am lacking knowledge in OpenMP

Comment: no, but each thread would need its own "result" string and then after the threads are finished you will concatenate them together to get the final string. Also, you may want to use string::reserve(), because adding one character at a time is otherwise potentially very slow.

Comment: I think OpenMP would probably be quite simple here. But there is the issue of loop dependence (`j++`). So you would have to give each thread a chunk size that is divisible by `gamma.length()`. What are the typical values of `ITERATION_COUNT` and `gamma.length()`?

Comment: @Qubit 20, 2000, 200000, 20000000, 2000000000

Comment: Which is which now? What I am mostly interested in is the ratio of `ITERATION_COUNT` and `gamma.length()`. That said, if `ITERATION_COUNT` is 20, then parallelisation will be slower. Given how simple the operation are in each iteration you would need at least 10E6 iterations for parallelisation to make sense, possible even more.

Comment: @Qubit you mean 1e6 = 10^6, right? Also I don't know if you saw it, but there is another modification of j in the first line of the loop which makes this much more complicated, I think.

Comment: Although I think it's easily resolvable by just not having a j altogether. instead just access gamma with ```i % gamma.size()```. Assuming that one doesn't need j afterwards.

Comment: I meant ```i % (gamma.length() - 1)```

Comment: @Paul, yes, i already did it

Comment: @Qubit, yes, I know that parallelization on small amounts of data will not give a speed gain. Nevertheless, I need to show it.
If I understand correctly, then you are interested in the value of gamma.length() - 1. The gamma value is always 4

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
void gammaEncoding(string const &input, string const &gamma, string &result)
{
    auto const old_length = result.size();
    result.resize(old_length + ITERATION_COUNT);

    #pragma omp parallel for default(none) \
        shared(input, gamma, result, old_length)
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATION_COUNT; ++i)
    {       
        int const Ti = input[i] - FIRST_SYMBOL;
        int const Gi = gamma[i % (gamma.length() - 1)] - FIRST_SYMBOL;
            
        result[old_length + i] = FIRST_SYMBOL + (Ti + Gi) % SYMBOL_NUMBER;
    }
}
```

This should do the same thing as your code does and be relatively fast (depending on problem size and number of processors). It does more work (one more modulo operator and in the worst case thread creation) which has to be amortized by the parallelism.

That being said, I have no idea if your original code does the right thing. For example I don't understand why one would not use all of gamma. Could it be that you think that `gamma[gamma.length() - 1] == '\0'`? Because that is **not** the case in C++ (assuming you are using std::string). Also I don't know if you actually plan to give non-empty `result` strings to the function. Because if you don't and if this function is not called in a loop such that you can reuse the `result` string instead of reallocating it every time, you might want to just create the `result` string inside the function. Due to RVO (Return Value Optimization), this would **not** create a copy operation at the end of the function, but instead put the string at the right position in the stack of the caller from the start. In the case that you want all of `gamma` **and** you wont reuse `result`:

```cpp
string gammaEncoding(string const &input, string const &gamma)
{
    string result(ITERATION_COUNT, ' ');

    #pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(input, gamma, result)
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATION_COUNT; ++i)
    {       
        int const Ti = input[i] - FIRST_SYMBOL;
        int const Gi = gamma[i % gamma.length()] - FIRST_SYMBOL;
            
        result[i] = FIRST_SYMBOL + (Ti + Gi) % SYMBOL_NUMBER;
    }
    return result;
}
```

One could further optimize this in such way that one doesn't have to do the additional modulo operation for every `i`, but then one could not use `pragma omp for`. In that case one would have to distribute the range of `i` in between the threads manually. Then one only has to calculate `j = i % gamma.length()` once and can then use the original if statement and `++j` to access `gamma`. In that case one would be dependent on the hardware to correctly predict the regular pattern in `j` such that the if statement is not holding you back. I could also add this solution, but I don't think that it is as good for learning to use OpenMP. Also I wouldn't guarantee that it actually is faster.